# WPF / XAML - Cannot get DevExpress tiles to work in unisn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress

I'm trying to have a cool tile feature in my app to where you can move the tile you want in position ans and the one you don't want just snaps back in place instead of navigating back and fourth from page to page. have them all on screeen but they just dont want to freakin cooperate. Is it in my XAML code and also should I be writing a C# method in order to make them work right. Please help I've been up all night fooling with this.

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:dxui="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/windowsui"
    xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
    xmlns:dxlc="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/layoutcontrol"         xmlns:dxb="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/bars" xmlns:dxr="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/ribbon" xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors" xmlns:ig="http://schemas.infragistics.com/xaml" x:Class="pNetWPFtile.MainWindow"
    dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="DXStyle" WindowStyle="None"
    WindowState="Maximized"
    Title="pNetWPFtile" Height="738.326" Width="900" AllowDrop="True">
<dx:BackgroundPanel>
    <DockPanel Margin="2,0">
        <Grid Width="888" Margin="0,0,0,-21">
            <StackPanel Margin="0,-12,1,593" Orientation="Vertical">
                <dxb:BarManager CreateStandardLayout="False" AllowDrop="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" RenderTransformOrigin="0.501,0.512">
                    <dxb:BarManager.Items>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem1" Content="New" LargeGlyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/Actions/New_32x32.png" RibbonStyle="All"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem2" Content="Open" LargeGlyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/Actions/Open_32x32.png" RibbonStyle="All"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem3" Content="Save" LargeGlyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/Save/Save_32x32.png" RibbonStyle="All"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem4" Content="Save As" LargeGlyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/Save/SaveAll_32x32.png" RibbonStyle="All"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem5" Content="Print" LargeGlyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/Print/Print_32x32.png" RibbonStyle="All"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem6" Content="Print Preview" LargeGlyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/Print/Preview_32x32.png" RibbonStyle="All"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem7" Content="Export" RibbonStyle="All" LargeGlyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/Export/ExportFile_32x32.png"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem8" Content="Redo" RibbonStyle="All" LargeGlyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/History/Redo_32x32.png"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem9" Content="Undo" RibbonStyle="All" LargeGlyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/History/Undo_32x32.png"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem10" Content="Copy" RibbonStyle="All" LargeGlyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/Edit/Copy_32x32.png"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem11" Content="Paste" RibbonStyle="All" LargeGlyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/Edit/Paste_32x32.png"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem12" Content="Cut" RibbonStyle="All" LargeGlyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/Edit/Cut_32x32.png"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem13" Content="Delete" RibbonStyle="All" LargeGlyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/Actions/DeleteList_32x32.png"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem14" Content="Zoom In" RibbonStyle="All" LargeGlyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/Zoom/ZoomIn_32x32.png"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem15" Content="Zoom Out" RibbonStyle="All" LargeGlyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/Zoom/ZoomOut_32x32.png"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem17" Content="Prev. Panel" RibbonStyle="All" LargeGlyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/Navigation/Backward_32x32.png"/>
                        <dxb:BarEditItem x:Name="barEditItem1" EditWidth="50" RibbonStyle="All">
                            <dxb:BarEditItem.EditSettings>
                                <dxe:TextEditSettings/>
                            </dxb:BarEditItem.EditSettings>
                        </dxb:BarEditItem>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem16" Content="Next Panel" RibbonStyle="All" LargeGlyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/Navigation/Forward_32x32.png"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem18" Content="Add Panel" RibbonStyle="All" LargeGlyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/Actions/AddFile_32x32.png"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem19" Content="Delete Panel" RibbonStyle="All" LargeGlyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/Actions/DeleteList_32x32.png"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem20" Content="Help" RibbonStyle="All" LargeGlyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/Miscellaneous/Content_32x32.png"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem21" Content="About" RibbonStyle="All" LargeGlyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/Support/Info_32x32.png"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem22" Content="barButtonItem22" Glyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/Support/Info_16x16.png"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem23" Content="barButtonItem23" Glyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/Programming/ProgrammingLanguage_16x16.png"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem24" Content="Connect to Server" LargeGlyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/Data/AddNewDataSource_32x32.png" RibbonStyle="All"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem25" Content="Diconnect Server" LargeGlyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/Data/DeleteDataSource_32x32.png" RibbonStyle="All"/>
                        <dxb:BarEditItem x:Name="barEditItem2" Content="x. y. Coordinates" RibbonStyle="All" Glyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/Tasks/Status_16x16.png" EditWidth="100">
                            <dxb:BarEditItem.EditSettings>
                                <dxe:TextEditSettings/>
                            </dxb:BarEditItem.EditSettings>
                        </dxb:BarEditItem>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem26" Content="Play"   RibbonStyle="All" Glyph="Images//play.png"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem27" Content="pause" RibbonStyle="All" Glyph="pack://application:,,,/pNetWPFtile;component/Images/pause1.png"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem28" Content="Stop" RibbonStyle="All" Glyph="pack://application:,,,/pNetWPFtile;component/Images/stop.png"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem29" RibbonStyle="All" Glyph="pack://application:,,,/pNetWPFtile;component/Images/rewind.png" Content="Rewind"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem30" Content="Foward" RibbonStyle="All" Glyph="pack://application:,,,/pNetWPFtile;component/Images/fast_forward.png"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem31" Content="Step Back" Glyph="pack://application:,,,/pNetWPFtile;component/Images/skip_backward.png" RibbonStyle="All"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem32" Content="Step Foward" Glyph="pack://application:,,,/pNetWPFtile;component/Images/skip_forward.png" LargeGlyph="pack://application:,,,/pNetWPFtile;component/Images/skip_forward.png" RibbonStyle="All"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem33" Content="Place" RibbonStyle="All" LargeGlyph="pack://application:,,,/pNetWPFtile;component/Images/Place.png"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem34" Content="Transition" RibbonStyle="All" Glyph="Images/tran.gif"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem35" Content="Arc" RibbonStyle="All" Glyph="Images/arc.gif"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem36" Content="Token" RibbonStyle="All" Glyph="Images/token.gif"/>
                        <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem37" Content="barButtonItem37"/>

                    </dxb:BarManager.Items>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <dxr:RibbonControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" RibbonStyle="Office2010">
                            <dxr:RibbonControl.ToolbarItemLinks>
                                <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem23"/>
                            </dxr:RibbonControl.ToolbarItemLinks>
                            <dxr:RibbonControl.PageHeaderItemLinks>
                                <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem22"/>
                            </dxr:RibbonControl.PageHeaderItemLinks>
                            <dxr:RibbonControl.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"     StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8DCAE6" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </dxr:RibbonControl.Background>
                            <dxr:RibbonControl.ApplicationMenu>
                                <dxr:ApplicationMenu/>
                            </dxr:RibbonControl.ApplicationMenu>
                            <dxr:RibbonDefaultPageCategory Caption="defaultCategory">
                                <dxr:RibbonPage Caption="File | Edit">
                                    <dxr:RibbonPageGroup Caption="Common" ShowCaptionButton="True">
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem1"/>
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem2"/>
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem3"/>
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem4"/>
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem5"/>
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem6"/>
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem7"/>
                                    </dxr:RibbonPageGroup>
                                    <dxr:RibbonPageGroup Caption="Edit" ShowCaptionButton="True">
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem8"/>
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem9"/>
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem10"/>
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem11"/>
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem12"/>
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem13"/>
                                    </dxr:RibbonPageGroup>
                                    <dxr:RibbonPageGroup Caption="Ribbon Page Group">
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem37"/>
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem37"/>
                                    </dxr:RibbonPageGroup>
                                </dxr:RibbonPage>
                                <dxr:RibbonPage Caption="Application Controls">
                                    <dxr:RibbonPageGroup Caption="Tools" ShowCaptionButton="True">
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem33"/>
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem34"/>
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem35"/>
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem36"/>
                                    </dxr:RibbonPageGroup>
                                    <dxr:RibbonPageGroup Caption="Controls" ShowCaptionButton="True">
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem26"/>
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem27"/>
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem28"/>
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem29"/>
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem30"/>
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink     BarItemName="barButtonItem31"/>
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem32"/>
                                    </dxr:RibbonPageGroup>
                                    <dxr:RibbonPageGroup Caption="Tiles Control" ShowCaptionButton="True">
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink         BarItemName="barButtonItem18"/>
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink     BarItemName="barButtonItem19"/>
                                    </dxr:RibbonPageGroup>
                                    <dxr:RibbonPageGroup Caption="Navigation" ShowCaptionButton="True">
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink     BarItemName="barButtonItem17"/>
                                        <dxb:BarEditItemLink     BarItemName="barEditItem1"/>
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink     BarItemName="barButtonItem16"/>
                                    </dxr:RibbonPageGroup>
                                    <dxr:RibbonPageGroup Caption="View"     ShowCaptionButton="True">
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink     BarItemName="barButtonItem14"/>
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink     BarItemName="barButtonItem15"/>
                                    </dxr:RibbonPageGroup>
                                </dxr:RibbonPage>
                                <dxr:RibbonPage Caption="Data Control">
                                    <dxr:RibbonPageGroup Caption="Table"     ShowCaptionButton="True"/>
                                    <dxr:RibbonPageGroup Caption="Rows &amp; Columns"     ShowCaptionButton="True"/>
                                    <dxr:RibbonPageGroup Caption="Server Settings"   ShowCaptionButton="True"     Glyph="pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v13.1;component/Images/Data/Database_16x16.    png">
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink   BarItemName="barButtonItem24"/>
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink   BarItemName="barButtonItem25"/>
                                    </dxr:RibbonPageGroup>
                                </dxr:RibbonPage>
                            </dxr:RibbonDefaultPageCategory>
                            <dxr:RibbonPageCategory Caption="Petri Net Editor - 2013"   Color="#FF7EC4EC">
                                <dxr:RibbonPage Caption="Help">
                                    <dxr:RibbonPageGroup Caption="Help">
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink   BarItemName="barButtonItem20"/>
                                        <dxb:BarButtonItemLink   BarItemName="barButtonItem21"/>
                                    </dxr:RibbonPageGroup>
                                </dxr:RibbonPage>
                            </dxr:RibbonPageCategory>
                        </dxr:RibbonControl>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="887"/>
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <DockPanel/>
                        </Grid>
                        <UniformGrid Width="887"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </dxb:BarManager>
            </StackPanel>
            <dxlc:TileLayoutControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,143,0,49"      Width="887" Orientation="Horizontal" MovingItemPlaceHolderBrush="{x:Null}">
                <dxlc:TileLayoutControl.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static     SystemColors.InactiveCaptionColorKey}}"/>
                </dxlc:TileLayoutControl.Background>
                <dxlc:Tile Header="Tile" Size="Small" Margin="-592,0,459,-449"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="270" Height="210" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                <dxlc:Tile Header="Tile" RenderTransformOrigin="0.243,0.336"     Margin="-592,-120,352,-69" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="270"/>
                <dxlc:Tile Header="Tile" Margin="-592,64,497,-65"  IsEnabled="False"     HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="270"/>
                <dxlc:Tile Header="Main panel" Size="Large" Margin="155,-110,-305,-110"     VerticalHeaderAlignment="Top" \ IsMaximized="True">
                    <Canvas/>
                </dxlc:Tile>
            </dxlc:TileLayoutControl>
            <dxe:RangeControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="1,707,0,0"     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="886">
                <dxe:RangeControl.OpacityMask>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static     SystemColors.ActiveBorderColorKey}}"/>
                </dxe:RangeControl.OpacityMask>
            </dxe:RangeControl>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</dx:BackgroundPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: I think I can fix this.

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress support directly?